# Timer tick increases

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I have a timer that has my enemy attack the player. The enemy attack subtracts 5 from the player's health. When the level loads(timerLevel) the game starts. When the game starts(timerGame), the enemy attack timer starts. When I kill the enemy, the enemy attack timer stops, the game timer stops, and the level timer starts again. It goes to the next level. The next level adds the enemy again and starts the game timer. Only now, the attack is subtracting 10 now instead of 5. How can I make the timer tick once when the game checks the level?

Excuse the sloppy code, still a noob at this.

Enemy class:

```
public var enemyAttackTimer:Timer = new Timer(8000);
enemyAttackTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerenemyattack);

        function timerenemyattack(event:TimerEvent)
        {
            if (Main.tileset[k].hitTestObject(Main.player.visionPoint))
            {
               Main.player -= 5
            }
        }
```

Main Class:

```
    private var onGameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);// For checking the Game
    private var onLevelTimer:Timer = new Timer(500, 1);//For checking the Level

    levelNumber = 1;
    onGameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerGame);
    onLevelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerLevel);
    onLevelTimer.start();

    //CREATE THE LEVEL AND ADD ENEMY/PLAYER
    function timerLevel(event:TimerEvent)
    {

        addChild(player);
        if (level.levelNumber == 1)
        {

            addChild(enemy)
            enemies = [enemy];

            enemy.enemyMoveTimer.start();
                enemy.enemyAttackTimer.start();

            onGameTimer.start();

        }
        if (level.levelNumber == 2)
        {

            addChild(enemy);
            addChild(enemy2);
            enemies = [enemy, enemy2];

            enemy.enemyMoveTimer.start();
            enemy.enemyAttackTimer.start();

            enemy2.enemyMoveTimer.start();
            enemy2.enemyAttackTimer.start();

            onGameTimer.start();
        }
        if (level.levelNumber == 3)
        {

            addChild(enemy);
            addChild(enemy2);
            enemies = [enemy, enemy2];

            enemy.enemyMoveTimer.start();
            enemy.enemyAttackTimer.start();

            enemy2.enemyMoveTimer.start();
            enemy2.enemyAttackTimer.start();
            onGameTimer.start();
        }
    }
    function timerGame(event:TimerEvent)
    {
    if (enemies.length == 0)
    {
                trace("NEXT LEVEL");
        var i:int = cellContainer.numChildren;
            while(i--)
        {
                cellContainer.removeChildAt(i);
        }
        levelNumber += 1;

        onLevelTimer.start();

        onGameTimer.stop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you care about removing your TimerEvent listeners, because if you don't, on the enemy for exemple, you could have the timer of the precedent enemy hitting your player and the new one too. 
Be carefull to stop your timers and remove your listeners when you don't need them anymore.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So Just stopping it isn't enough. I'd have to removeEventListener?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes stopping should be enough but while you have listeners attached to your Timer flash cannot free memory used by the Timer because it is still registered by the event listener. It's always better to remove events listeners when you don't need them anymore. And it's always better to dispose objects when you don't need them anymore. I hope your program run well now :)